How to get all organizations from Atlassian with API?
If get organization in a solid subdomain, this way works:
curl --request GET \
--url 'https://mysubdomain.atlassian.net/rest/servicedeskapi/organization' \
--user 'my@email.com:<access_token>' \
--header 'Accept: application/json'

But this way doesn't work:
curl --request GET \
--url 'https://api.atlassian.com/admin/v1/orgs' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer <access_token>' \
--header 'Accept: application/json'

Also this way doesn't work:
curl --request GET \
--url 'https://api.atlassian.com/admin/v1/orgs' \
--user 'my@email.com:<access_token>' \
--header 'Accept: application/json'

The error code is:
{"code":401,"message":"Unauthorized"}

The access token was created on this page:
https://id.atlassian.com/manage-profile/security/api-tokens
Why it doesn't work?
